# How to display popup box in dropdown after clicking AddNewQuantity in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-services

In Html :

```
      <select class="form-control" id="quantity" (click)="onChangequantity(quantity)" [(ngModel)]="model.quantity" name="quantity" #quantity="ngModel">
                 <option value="addquantity">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                       Add New Quantity 
                 </option>    
                 <hr><br/> 
                 <option>Kg</option>  
      </select>
```

In component.ts

```
onChangequantity(event) {
    console.log(event.value)
    if (event.value === 'addquantity') {
      this.router.navigate(['/pages/products/quantity']);
    }
  }
```

Here i have used routing concept but i no need this when i click Add New Quantity it should display popup box.

Comment: what type of pop up? why are you routing then?

Comment: Actually in quantity it has only two input fields so i  kept separate component but now i dont want that routing method. if i click Add New quantity from dropdown the popup box should open.

Comment: previously did you any popup in your component?

Comment: yes i have used it. But now i want in dropdown list.                                               
        <button   class="btn btn-outline"  style="height:0px" [nbPopover]="form" >Add &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>